# Listbox not displaying deserialized JSON data

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, windows-phone-8, listbox

I came across this problem for days , I couldnt solve it. The listbox in my windows phone is not displaying anything. I am not even sure whether the json deser works.

A json sample code is inside within the c# code commented.

This is the part of C# in WP8

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webserv.maintain_serverPortTypeClient tables = new webserv.maintain_serverPortTypeClient();
    tables.view_tableAsync();
    tables.view_tableCompleted += new EventHandler<webserv.view_tableCompletedEventArgs>(tbviewcomplete);
}

public void tbviewcomplete(object obj, webserv.view_tableCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
    // var table_json = e.Result.ToString();

    // var table_json = "[{\"tableID\":\"61\",\"size\":\"4\",\"zone\":\"Non-Smoking\",\"area\":\"Outdoor\"},{\"tableID\":\"62\",\"size\":\"4\",\"zone\":\"Non-Smoking\",\"area\":\"Outdoor\"},{\"tableID\":\"63\",\"size\":\"4\",\"zone\":\"Smoking\",\"area\":\"Indoor\"},{\"tableID\":\"64\",\"size\":\"30\",\"zone\":\"Smoking\",\"area\":\"Indoor\"}]";
    //   MyTables[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTables[]>(table_json);

    List<MyTables> gesult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyTables>>(e.Result);
    tableview.ItemsSource = gesult;
}

public class MyTables
{
    public string table_id { get; set; }
    public string table_size { get; set; }
    public string table_zone { get; set; }
    public string table_area { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the part of the XAML code.

```
<ListBox x:Name="tableview" ItemsSource="{Binding data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Height="474" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding}">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Text="{Binding table_id}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding table_size}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding table_zone}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding table_area}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


</ListBox>
```

I do not know where went wrong and it doesnt display. Please drop me down some advice. I am very new to c# and Json.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint does `gesult` contain a number of results as expected?

Comment: Tnx Brent for edit. Now the question makes much more sense. @user3159789, questions cannot contain tags, that's why your question has been edited.

Comment: Oh I see , I didnt know as I am new to stackoverflow. Apparently this is my first post. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing what you want, first either you must use the exact field names used in *JSON* string or use `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract` and `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember` attributes to decorate `MyTable` class and its properties in order to use arbitrary property names. So `MyTable` class would look like this without contract:

```
public class MyTable
{
    public string tableID { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public string area { get; set; }
}
```

or like this with `DataContract`:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

...

[DataContract]
public class MyTable
{
    [DataMember(Name = "tableID")]
    public string table_id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public int table_size { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "zone")]
    public string table_zone { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "area")]
    public string table_area { get; set; }
}
```

Note that, *JSON* field name can be specified using `Name` property of `DataMember` attribute. This way, you can use **any** property name in your class `MyTable`.

Then, use this to deserialize your *JSON* string:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MyTable>));
string table_json = e.Result.ToString();
List<MyTable> result;
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(table_json)))
{
    result = (List<MyTable>)ser.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Note that you must add `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` to your project references.

Comment: Thank Mr Arin! You've teach me something new , and thank you for the help. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

and C# code:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public MyDataClass(string artist, int duration)
    {
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
        Artist = artist;
        Duration = span.ToString();
    }
}

public void AudioGet()
{
    var clientAudio = new WebClient();
    clientAudio.OpenReadCompleted += clientAudio_OpenReadCompleted;
    string uri = "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?";
    clientAudio.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri));
}

private void clientAudio_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<MyDataClass> audioList = new List<MyDataClass>();
    var root = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
    RootObject rootObject = (RootObject)root.ReadObject(e.Result);

    foreach (var myClass in rootObject.response)
    {
        audioList.Add(new MyDataClass(myClass.artist, myClass.duration));
    }

    MyListBox.ItemsSource = audioList;
}

#region JsonDataClass
public class Response
{
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```